# mark a contact with app logo

Tags: android, android-contacts, graphical-logo

I basically have a list of contacts in my app, I want to mark certain contacts on the list with the logo of my app if they are registered on my database. I have sorted out the server integration, but not sure how to add my logo to the contact list.

Examples of apps that have done something similar: Viber and Rebtel.

EDIT: the cycle of it is as such:

1. I query my app for all the usernames
2. I post these to the server
3. the server returns a string like: "server says:1=johndoe" as the common username
4. how would I take that string and and mark "johndoe" as a registered user?

My getView is:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_contact_item, null);}

    final Contact contact = (Contact)getItem(position);

        if(contact != null){
            final TextView DisplayName = (TextView)
            view.findViewById(R.id.screen_contacts_item_textView);
    DisplayName.setText(contact.getDisplayName());}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by:

```
for (Contact contact : list) {
        List<PhoneNumber> ListAllNumbers = contact.getPhoneNumbers();

        for (PhoneNumber aNum : ListAllNumbers) {

            for (String anAppNum : compareServer) {
                if (aNum.getNumber().contentEquals(anAppNum)) {
                    contact.setAppContact(true);
                    Log.i(TAG, contact.getDisplayName() + " is registered");
                }
```

Then in the getView, I added an if statement to set a drawable to the contact if it is an AppContact, or set drawable to hidden if they are not.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `getView` callback to insert your logic code there

you need to inflate a layout for the contact row with the icon and ask if the user is register display that image otherwise  gone that image

here is [example](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) of this

Comment: inside your xml R.layout.screen_contact_item add imageView and  ask here if the user is register or not like this:  if (contact.isRegister) { //display icon } else{ // gone the icon}

Comment: sorry how would I construct the if statement? I know it would be along the lines of if(contact.isRegistered){show image} but how can i determine the "isRegistered" from the String returned from the server?

Comment: if (1=johndoe) { // means register and if(0=johndoe)// means not register

Comment: but what if the String returns several values?

Comment: so build your state machine correct, the implementation is up to you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15414/discussion-between-tomer-and-faz15)